# \newcommand verbatim parameter

Tags: macros, verbatim, pdfpages

I am trying to make a command that looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\pdf}[1]{ 
    \includepdf[
        scale = 0.7,
        pagecommand = 
            \begin{verbatim} 
                #1             
            \end{verbatim}
    ]{#1}
}
```

such that

```
\pdf{Test.pdf}
```

includes the pdf and prints the filename on top of the page.

I get the error `File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim`. I also tried it without the verbatim:

```
\newcommand{\pdf}[1]{\includepdf[scale=0.7,pagecommand= #1 ]{#1}}
```

This displays the pdf correctly, but when the filename has an underscore (eg `test_file.pdf`), I get errors `Missing $ inserted` and the filename is not displayed correctly. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't use `verbatim` as the argument to another command. What you need is `\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}`.

Comment: @egreg An answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`verbatim`, like `\verb`, cannot be used in the argument to another command.

What you seem to need is just

```
\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}
```

so the underscore becomes printable:

```
\newcommand{\pdf}[1]{%
  \includepdf[
    scale = 0.7,
    pagecommand = \texttt{\detokenize{#1}},
  ]{#1}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much:) I have been searching for \detokenize{} for quite some time.